# jquery autocomplete matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, autosuggest

I'm using this [JQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete). It seems that by default it matches from the start, so "foo" would match "fool", but not "bufoon".

I want the matching to occur anywhere and case insensitively, such that "foo" would match

- fool
- bufoon
- Foo Fighter

The options don't appear to be documented anywhere, so I had a look though the [source code](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js) to figure out if this is possible but couldn't find any obvious way to change the matching algorithm, but I find it hard to believe this isn't supported.

Comment: I migrated to the jQuery UI version from this and really enjoy the change.

Answer (score 4):

There is an option, `matchContains`, that is false by default. Set it to true. [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zAzj4/)

[**Here is a list of options**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions). Be Sure to click the "options" tab

Comment: That's much easier than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar. That's how you can do it:

```
.autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response) {
        var term = request.term.toLowerCase();
        // generating the array which matches the search term.
        response(autocompleteArr);
    }
});
```